# Grails domain objects - limit access to specific user

Tags: security, grails, grails-orm

Is there a way to limit access to Grails domain objects across the board to the owner of the object?

For example, I can make an `assert` easily, but I don't want to duplicate that everywhere, or risk missing a spot.

This isn't exactly the same as multi-tenancy because it's not just a tenant ID - it may be specific business logic for different domain objects.

```
class MyDomain {
  String name
  String user
}

class MyController {
  def show(Long id) {
    def obj = MyDomain.get(id)
    // *** How do I not do copy-paste this line in each individual controller 
    // that touches MyDomain?? *** 
    assert obj.user == CURRENT_USER

    return obj
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are so many ways to handle such scenarios, as other answers are suggesting, however, I think one proper way to approach it is to use [Spring Security Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core) and [spring-security-acl plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-acl). ACL plugin will drill down into object level and helps you to control

According to [doc](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-acl)

> "The ACL plugin adds Domain Object Security support to a Grails
>   application that uses Spring Security."

The combination of both security core and ACL can help you accomplish what you need.

Comment: Spring Security looks like it still has to be applied at each service or controller method. I was hoping for something that went into the domain / GORM layer itself.

Comment: Have you looked at spring-security-acl plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Filter might be one way, another way is to adjust your queries if possible.  You would probably need to be able to search for some other criteria other than the ID.  Without understanding your use case a little more, it is hard to give a better answer.

```
def show(String someValue) {
  def currentUser = howeverYouGetYourUser
  def obj = MyDomain.findByUserAndSomeValue(currentUser, someValue)
  if (obj) {
    // yeah!!!
  } else { 
    // boo!!
  } 
}
```

Ideally, if you are looking for specific data for a specific user, ID isn't really the way to go.

Comment: Yes of course I can do that - the point was to put something lower in the stack so if I do MyDomain.find(x) by itself, I don't accidentally pull someone else's stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Iam not sure if you can do it in domain level but one way is using filters. There is a filters plugin available for Grails. Keep the User in session and verify in filter for each request..

Sample filter code:

```
class SecurityFilters {
    def filters = {
        loginCheck(controller: '*', action: '*') {
            before = {
                if (!session.user && !actionName.equals('login')) {
                    redirect(action: 'login')
                    return false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and specify the filter attributes..

Here is the documentation grails.org/doc/2.2.1/ref/Plug-ins/filters.html